# How to change the select option for a specific interval

Tags: php

I want to change the below code to PHP WHILE and get output using PHP code instead of HTML.

```
<select name="passyear" id="passyear">
<option></option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

Please help me

```
<select name="passyear" id="passyear">
<option></option>
<?php
$year= date("Y");  
$i=$year-9 ;
do{
     echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
} 
while ($i <= $year); 
?>
</select>
```

What is my mistake ? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not changing $i in the loop. This is easier with for, but a while works fine too.

```
<select name="passyear" id="passyear">
<option></option>
<?php

$year= date("Y") - 9;

$i = 0;
while ($i <= 9) {
    $y = $year + $i++;
    echo "<option value='$y'>$y</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/af6da73411b082):

```
<select name="passyear" id="passyear">
<option></option>
<option value='2006'>2006</option>
<option value='2007'>2007</option>
<option value='2008'>2008</option>
<option value='2009'>2009</option>
<option value='2010'>2010</option>
<option value='2011'>2011</option>
<option value='2012'>2012</option>
<option value='2013'>2013</option>
<option value='2014'>2014</option>
<option value='2015'>2015</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ohh Thanks, I miss the  `$i++` after echo.